# Why robocopy with multi-treading copies faster

Tags: copy, robocopy, multi-threading

I have been using robocopy with the switch MT and really makes a difference in coping time.

I would like to know why the CPU treads act as a bottle-neck while copying files or what makes robocopy with multi-treading copy faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's faster because you're copying more than one file at once.

It's possible to overdo it;  if you use /MT:64 (for example) on a desktop with limited resources it'll grind to a halt, but in general:  If you have the RAM, the CPU, the disk IO, and the network to support it, multithreading is faster because you're copying more than one file at a time.